# How does this "for" structure works in python

Tags: python

I have searched for a code for converting .csv rows into vectors for using the dataset in my DL project with Tensorflow. I've found this code:

```
import numpy as np
def extract_data(filename):
    #arrays to hold the labels and features vectors
   labels = []
   fvecs= []

    #iterate over the rows,spplit the label from the features
    #convert labels to integers and features to floats
    for line in file(filename):
       row = line.split(',')
       labels.append(int(row[0]))
       fvecs.append([float(x) for x in row[1:2]])
   #convert the array of float arrays into a numpy float matrix
   fvecs_np = np.matrix(fvecs).astype(np.float33)
   #convert the array of int labels into numpy array
   labels_np = np.array(labels).astype(dtype=np.uint8)
   #convert the int numpy array into a one_hot matrix
   label_onehot = (np.arrange(NUM_LABELS) == labels_np[:,None])).astype(np.float32)
   #return a pair of the features matrix and the one_hot label matrix
   return fvecs_np, label_onehot
```

I tried to go through the code and learn it.Then, i've encountered this line:

```
fvecs.append([float(x) for x in row[1:2]])
```

It appears that it can get value of second and third indices of each row and feed it to x but i can't fully understand why he used `float(x)` before `for` and why he surrounded the `for` loop with brackets and then appending it to `fvecs`

Comment: Check out [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: It's list comprehension (look in the docs!). The float() part is for converting each value into a float

Comment: It is called list comprehension.

Comment: It's called list comprehensions as stated before and, to expand a bit on @ÓscarLópez comment, the float(x) it's because line.split(',') is returning a list of strings so you have to convert each of these strings to a float.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you understand:

```
# create a list of ints
x = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
print('x: ', x)

# create an identical list to x
y = [element for element in x]
print('y: ', y)

# create a list where each element is the square of the elment in x
s = [element**2 for element in x]
print('s: ', s)

# append a list to a list (to make a list of lists)
d = []
d.append(x)
d.append(s)
print('d: ', d)

# doing it all together
d = []
d.append([-2, -1, 0, 1, 1]) # the same as d.append(x)
d.append([element**2 for element in x]) # the same as d.append(s)
print('d_again: ', d)
```

The output:

```
('x: ', [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2])
('y: ', [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2])
('s: ', [4, 1, 0, 1, 4])
('d: ', [[-2, -1, 0, 1, 2], [4, 1, 0, 1, 4]])
('d_again: ', [[-2, -1, 0, 1, 1], [4, 1, 0, 1, 4]])
```

The use of list comprehension is considered "pythonic"